# Why isn't my way of defining curl correct? Or is it?

Tags: curl

Why isn't the implicit (explicit ?) definition of curl something along these lines:

$$curl \ \mathbf{F} \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \lim_{V \to 0}\left( \frac{1}{V}\int_{\partial V} \mathbf{\hat{n}} \times (\mathbf{F} - (\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}})\mathbf{\hat{n}}) \ dS\right)$$

vs. the actual definition:

$$(curl \ \mathbf{F}) \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \lim_{A \to 0}\left( \frac{1}{|A|}\oint_{C} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{s}\right)$$

In words, take the integral over a sphere (without loss of generality) of the projection of the vector field onto the tangent plane of the sphere. Finally, divide by the volume of the sphere and take the limit as the sphere shrinks to zero volume. The cross product converts the tangent to an axis tangent.

Pardon me if the equation is not entirely correct - it's the idea I'm trying emphasize.

Intuitively, this is how I would define curl. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Just a comment: It appears your definition sets $curl (\mathbf{F})$ as a scalar quantity, whereas the actual definition, upon dotting with the unit vector, gives a scalar. The latter makes sense; but consider how to edit your def'n (does it make sense to just dot your LHS with $\mathbf{n}$ as well?)

Comment: In (F - (F . n) n) dS, dS is not dotted with (F - (F . n)n). So the integral is a vector quantity. Or at least it is meant to be!!!

Comment: I have since come across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754909/how-can-i-prove-that-these-definitions-of-curl-are-equivalent), which addresses the concerns that sent me down this road to begin with. But I still wonder if my definition has any validity. If so, then it is also an equivalent definition, but perhaps less useful.

Comment: dS should not have been a vector (bold) - changed dS from bold to regular text.

Comment: What are $V$, $\delta v$, $A$ and $C$?