# Deriving 2-D curl from the formal definition, the hard way

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curl

The curl of $\mathbf{F}$ at some point $(x_0,y_0)$ is defined as $$\lim_{A\to0}\frac{1}{|A|}\oint_\gamma\mathbf{F}\cdot ds$$
I was curious to see what happens when we expand this, in the simple two dimensional case, and where I simply let $\gamma$ enclose a circle, $A$, so rewriting:
$$\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt$$
$$\gamma(t)=\begin{pmatrix}x_0+r\cos t\\y_0+r\sin t\end{pmatrix},\mathbf{F}=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{F}_1\\\mathbf{F}_2\end{pmatrix}$$
And I am stuck after the following steps, which may or may not have a confused misapplication of integration by parts! I am not sure how this works in multivariable calculus. Note also that any appearance of $x,y$ in the following refers to the $x$ and $y$ coords returned by $\gamma$, which $\mathbf{F}$ takes in:
$$\begin{align*}&\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}_2(\gamma(t))\cdot r\cos t\,dt-\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}_1(\gamma(t))\cdot r\sin t\,dt\right)
\\&=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}_2(\gamma(t))\cdot\cos t\,dt-\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}_1(\gamma(t))\cdot\sin t\,dt\right)
\\&=\lim_{r\to0}-\frac{1}{\pi r}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sin t\left(-r\sin t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_2}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+
r\cos t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_2}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\,dt+\\\int_0^{2\pi}\cos t\left(-r\sin t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_1}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+r\cos t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_1}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}\right)\,dt\right)
\\&=\lim_{r\to0}-\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int_0^{2\pi}\sin t\left(r\sin^2 t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_2}{\partial x}+r\cos^2 t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_2}{\partial y}\right)\,dt+
\\\int_0^{2\pi}\cos t\left(r\sin^2 t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_1}{\partial x}+r\cos^2 t\frac{\partial\mathbf{F}_1}{\partial y}\right)\,dt\right)\end{align*}$$
And it is at this point that I have no idea how to proceed, since continuing to integrate by parts would yield nothing, I think. And in a limit letting $r\to0$ would zero out the entire expression, so I am sure I have made a mistake somewhere. Going from the second line to the third, I noticed that in an integration by parts, the term outside the integral would have either $\sin,\cos$ which would zero out at the evaluation points $0,2\pi$. I also presumed that the one-dimensional integration by parts process of integrating one, differentiating the other, would correlate to me needing to find the *directional* derivative of $\mathbf{F}_1,\mathbf{F}_2$ w.r.t $t$, which also would need a chain rule expansion. I thought this would require $\nabla_\mathbf{F}\cdot\gamma'(t)$. This may also be the source of my mistake, but I haven't a clue.

Comment: Nitpick: Either it's $\oint_\gamma\mathbf{F}\cdot\,ds$, or it's $\int_0^{2\pi}\mathbf{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt$. Never $\oint_\gamma\mathbf{F}(\gamma(t))\cdot\gamma'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: If you're trying to derive the formula for curl in cartesian coordinates, then using circles is probably not a good idea; using squares centered at the point $(x_0,y_0)$ is better. I've actually written up an answer a while back for [formula of curl in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3760808/568204), hopefully reading that will allow you to specialize to your case. (Also, what you have in your first equal sign is not the equal to the curl; it is only one of the components of the curl.)

Comment: @peek-a-boo how else? Would it be easier and still accurate to consider $A$ as a square around $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo plus, your answer is highly formal and I need a little assistance: what is the meaning of the braces <$F,\tau$>, <$H,n$>? Is this the vector notation <$x,y$> or something else?

Comment: yup, squares are good. Then $\gamma$ is a union of the 4 straight lines, so you'll have 4 integrals, which you can group together into two pairs of 2 terms, involving differences of $F_1$ and $F_2$ at various points. Then, you apply the integral and differential mean-value theorem. THe braces $\langle \rangle$ refer to the dot product $\cdot$ (so $\int\langle F,\tau\rangle\,dl$ is the same as your $\int\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}$ etc; I didn't use boldface in that answer for the vector fields because it was too much typing for me).

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you

Comment: oh and having thought about it somemore, you should ignore my paranthetical remark in my first comment. In two-dimensions only, it makes sense to think of the curl as a scalar as in your first expression.