# Why can these two expressions be equal in the curl and divergence?

Tags: integration, inner-products, outer-product

I have the same question in here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/741463/why-can-these-two-expression-be-equal-in-the-curl-and-divergence

But honestly i am not sure that this question should belong to  mathematics or physics,so i post this question here and there,hoping someone can explain to me!thankyou!

1.The expression  of curl of $\vec A$ is  $\nabla\times \vec A$,and the calculation of $\nabla\times \vec A$ is as belowed

$\nabla\times \vec A= 
\begin{vmatrix}
\vec u_x & \vec u_y & \vec u_z \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \\
A_x & A_y & A_z \\
\end{vmatrix}
$

2.The definition of curl of $\vec A$ is  $\lim_{S\to 0} 
 \frac{ \vec{u}_n \oint_c\vec{A}\cdot d \vec{l_c}}{\Delta S}$

So if we combine 1. and 2. ,we can know

$ 
\begin{vmatrix}
\vec u_x & \vec u_y & \vec u_z \\
\frac{\partial }{\partial x} & \frac{\partial }{\partial y} & \frac{\partial }{\partial z} \\
A_x & A_y & A_z \\
\end{vmatrix}
=\lim_{S\to 0} 
 \frac{ \vec{u}_n \oint_c\vec{A}\cdot d \vec{l_c}}{\Delta S}$

i want to ask why can they be equal?why can the curl of A be written as $\nabla\times \vec A$?

I have the same question in the divergence
$\nabla\cdot \vec A=\lim_{\Delta v\to 0} 
 \frac{ \oint_s\vec{A}\cdot d\vec s}{\Delta v}$

I think the reason of this question is that i think according to the definition of inner product  or outer product,they should be no relation with  integral,but now these equations told me they do have the relation,so i can not understand this.

Comment: You may wanna check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754909/how-can-i-prove-that-these-definitions-of-curl-are-equivalent

Comment: @Luchoming thankyou,i will study this hardly